# Accessing On-Prem SQL Server from Azure without using an On-Prem data gateway in between

Tags: azure-logic-apps, data-gateway

Can we access an on-premise SQL Server without using an on-premise Data Gateway from Azure? is there any other work around? like with a compromise in security/protocol?  I am doing a POC project and would like to access an on-premise SQL Server from LogicApps without using any data gateway bridge in between...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for development, absolutely yes, you can use some tools like `ngrok` to expose your on-premise SQL Server without any public IP or Domain in internet to create a TCP tunnel for listening the port `1433` of SQL Server, as the section [`TCP tunnel`](https://ngrok.com/docs#tcp) of `ngork` document said.

However, it is **not stable so that can not be used on production**. For a PoC project, I think it's available and good enough. But when you want to deploy it as a stable service, to **use Azure VPN Gateway is an only available & stable solution** if there is not a public internet address for your on-premise SQL Database.